# Importing COLLADA(.dae) file into blender using python

Tags: python, blender

I got a project in which I've to import different files into blender. I am just a starter to blender and it's python API. I am looking for a way to import .dae file into blender using a python script. Until now I've been unsuccessful to find an import module in python for blender.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8):

While most import/export operators can be found in `bpy.ops` such as `bpy.ops.import_mesh.obj()` the collada import/export operators are under `bpy.ops.wm`. The importer is `bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath="")`.

If your automating the import of many files you will want to use `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath="")` to save each one as you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(...)
```

However, you may need to pass the options

```
auto_connect = True, 
find_chains = True, 
fix_orientation = True
```

these are seen as important to properly import the rig structure.
Here is how I load the collada file.

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath = path, 
                      auto_connect = True, 
                      find_chains = True, 
                      fix_orientation = True)
```

If still there are some issues in collada import, do check the other options available in the API.